# How to send an javascript array to my database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I'm stuck because I don't understand what's wrong with my query, can someone look into it ?

Basically, I'm using ajax to send my array to php, and then using php to send my data to my table, but it doesn't send anything

Here my javascript

```js
// ENVOI DE LA GRILLE VERS LE SERVEUR
            var col_tab = document.getElementById('grille').rows[0].cells;
            var type_tab = document.getElementById('grille').rows[1].cells;
            var nb_cols = document.getElementById('grille').rows[0].cells.length;
            var titre_col=[];
            var type_col;

            var lignes_tab = document.getElementById('grille').rows;
            var nb_lignes = document.getElementById('grille').rows.length;
            var contenu_cell=[];
            var nb_options;
            var options;

            for (var ind=1; ind<nb_cols; ind++)
            {
                titre_col[ind-1] = col_tab[ind].children[4].value;
                type_col = type_tab[ind].children[0].type;
                options = "";

                if (type_col == "text")
                {
                    for (var indlg=1; indlg<nb_lignes; indlg++)
                    {
                        contenu_cell[ind-1] = lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].value;
                    }
                }
                else if (type_col == "number")
                {
                    for (var indlg=1; indlg<nb_lignes; indlg++)
                    {
                        contenu_cell[ind-1] = "Min=" + lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].attributes["min"].value + " Max=" + lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].attributes["max"].value;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (var indlg=1; indlg<nb_lignes; indlg++)
                    {
                        nb_options = lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].children.length;
                        for (var indop = 0; indop<nb_options; indop++)
                        {
                            options += lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].children[indop].text + "|";
                        }
                        contenu_cell[ind-1] = options;
                    }
                }

                $.post('ajout.php',{titre_col:titre_col,contenu_cell:contenu_cell,ind:ind});
            }
```

Here my php

```php
<?php

$connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=innovatech", "root", "12345");

if(isset($_POST["titre_col"]))
{
    $titre_col = $_POST['titre_col'];
    $contenu_cell = $_POST['contenu_cell'];
    $ind = $_POST['ind'];
    sleep(5);
    $query = "
    INSERT INTO colonne_grille 
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) VALUES 
    (:titre_col[0], :titre_col[1], :titre_col[2], :titre_col[3], :titre_col[4], :titre_col[5], :titre_col[6], :titre_col[7], :titre_col[8], :titre_col[9],)
    ";
        $user_data = array(
            ':titre_col' => $_POST["titre_col"],
        );
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($user_data);

        $query = "
    INSERT INTO ligne_grille 
    (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, num_ligne) VALUES 
    (:contenu_cell[0], :contenu_cell[1], :contenu_cell[2], :contenu_cell[3], :contenu_cell[4], :contenu_cell[5], :contenu_cell[6], :contenu_cell[7], :contenu_cell[8], :contenu_cell[9], :ind)
    ";
        $user_data = array(
            ':contenu_cell' => $_POST["contenu_cell"],
            ':ind' => $_POST["ind"],
        );
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute($user_data);
}

?>
```

Here a picture of my tables
[tables image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vCdt.png)

Here a picture of an exemple of what's in my arrays
[exemple of variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE8Ki.png)

As you can see in my javascript, I'm creating 2 arrays (`titre_col[]` and `contenu_cell[]`).
And then, I'm sending those 2 arrays into my php with ajax (`$.post('ajout.php',{titre_col:titre_col,contenu_cell:contenu_cell,ind:ind};`).
And finally, I get those arrays (`$titre_col = $_POST['titre_col'];
    $contenu_cell = $_POST['contenu_cell'];`) and I send them to my tables

Can someone help me fix this issue ?

Thanks guys, stay safe !! :)

Comment: you need to use JSON.stringify on your POST 2nd parameter

Comment: @ControlAltDel Hello, thank you for your reply, I've never used JSON in my life, so I'm not quite sure how to do that, you mean write this : ```$.post('ajout.php',JSON.stringify({titre_col:titre_col,contenu_cell:contenu_cell,ind:ind}));``` ? Thank you for your time

Comment: Exactly. I have added an answer with your updated code with the change

Answer (score 0):

Just use JSON.stringify on the 2nd parameter of $.post

```
// ENVOI DE LA GRILLE VERS LE SERVEUR
            var col_tab = document.getElementById('grille').rows[0].cells;
            var type_tab = document.getElementById('grille').rows[1].cells;
            var nb_cols = document.getElementById('grille').rows[0].cells.length;
            var titre_col=[];
            var type_col;

            var lignes_tab = document.getElementById('grille').rows;
            var nb_lignes = document.getElementById('grille').rows.length;
            var contenu_cell=[];
            var nb_options;
            var options;

            for (var ind=1; ind<nb_cols; ind++)
            {
                titre_col[ind-1] = col_tab[ind].children[4].value;
                type_col = type_tab[ind].children[0].type;
                options = "";

                if (type_col == "text")
                {
                    for (var indlg=1; indlg<nb_lignes; indlg++)
                    {
                        contenu_cell[ind-1] = lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].value;
                    }
                }
                else if (type_col == "number")
                {
                    for (var indlg=1; indlg<nb_lignes; indlg++)
                    {
                        contenu_cell[ind-1] = "Min=" + lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].attributes["min"].value + " Max=" + lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].attributes["max"].value;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (var indlg=1; indlg<nb_lignes; indlg++)
                    {
                        nb_options = lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].children.length;
                        for (var indop = 0; indop<nb_options; indop++)
                        {
                            options += lignes_tab[indlg].cells[ind].children[0].children[indop].text + "|";
                        }
                        contenu_cell[ind-1] = options;
                    }
                }

                $.post('ajout.php',JSON.stringify({titre_col:titre_col,contenu_cell:contenu_cell,ind:ind})");
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it still doesn't seem to work (I supposed there is no ```"``` at the end of the $.post, but even without, it still doesn't send the data to my database). I suppose my SQL query is wrong, but then I can't quite get where the issue comes from

Comment: Is it reaching PHP? If so, then it is only a matter of formatting your DB / SQL insert. And you can tweak that by directly querying your DB, and then seeing how the sql request in PHP is different

Comment: I am sorry but I have no idea how to test if it is reaching PHP. I tried doing :  ```echo $_POST['contenu_cell'];``` but I get this error : ```Notice: Undefined index: num_ligne in C:\wamp\www\innovatech\ajout.php on line 75``` :(

Comment: When I do a ```print_r($_POST)``` I get this : ```Array ( [titre] => test [contenu_cell] => [listgri] => 0 )```